# Limit Qt API to specific version?

Tags: api, qt

is it possible to reduce/limit the Qt API features to **specific earlier versions**?
In the API documentation there is e.g. information that methods are **introduced** with version **major.minor**.
Can you ***restrict the API features*** of an installed newer version to the earlier ones without installing?
I don't think so, because there are no version conditions in the header files.
But maybe you know for sure...

Is there a **tool** which detects the usage of **incompatible API** to a specific version?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I don't think so. Configure your CI to build and test with the minimum version is the best you can do, I think.

Comment: Well, my distribution provides a version I'm happy with, but I'm fixing some bugs in a Github project and the installed CI is very outdated/unsupported and is back at Qt 5.2. It's a bit cumbersome to check the docs or ping pong trial and error with the CI. And the Qt download archive got cleaned up. No 5.2.

Comment: @Markus You can still download Qt 5.2: http://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/5.2/

Comment: Doh. Stupid. There is also https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/ where you find the newest releases, which you don't find at new_archive. Maybe a left over... good to know. Thx